# In Excel, how can I condition a column so it will go through 2 columns of numbers and print yes if there are dupes, else it will be no?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Not sure if there is a way to scan or rearrange columns so they can match other columns. My problem has lots of unique ID numbers.
For example:

```
Column1  Column2       Column3
6        2              6
4        4              4
7        6              7
1        7              1
2        [EMPTY]        2
5        1              No Dupe for 5
[EMPTY]  99             No Dupe for 99
```

Column1 is registered member's ID no. and column2 is people who checked in. There are times when people input incorrect ID no. Column3 is to check if that person is registered in Column1.
Im simply trying to do the attendance of people who checked in so i can send them the required notes for the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good start:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,B$2:B$7,0)),"No dupe for "&A2,A2)
```

The `MATCH()` checks if the entry is found. If yes, it puts the value. If not, it puts "No dupe for ", followed by the value.